# Storing an object in dictionary without calling constructor

Tags: c#, .net

I currently have an interface for detectors, which is called "Model". In my factory class, I have this function called CreateDetector, which returns the appropriate Model of the detector.

```
public Detector CreateDetector(string modelName, string ip, string port) {
    if ( modelName = "A" )
    {
        return new ModelA(ip, port);
    }
    if ( modelName = "B" )
    {
        return new ModelB(ip, port);
    }
    ...
}
```

To me, this seems rather inefficient and the code is repeated multiple times. In scenarios similar to this, I would normally use the following approach.

```
public Detector CreateDetector(string modelName, string ip, string port) {
    Dictionary<string, Detector> detectors = new Dictionary<string, Detector>()
    {
        { "A", new ModelA(ip, port) },
        { "B", new ModelB(ip, port) },
        ...
    };
        return detectors[modelName]
}
```

However, in the current implementation of Detector, the base constructor always calls Init(), which attempts to connect to the devices. Obviously, I do not want to connect X amount of times to the device, as this could cause a multitude of issues. (This part is what got me to ask the question, I understand a constructor should not be heavy, but this is legacy code which will not be changed.)

I would like the end result to simulate something like this, where the dictionary just contains a declaration of the object, but the constructor is only called once it is determined which class you are using.

```
public Detector CreateDetector(string modelName, string ip, string port) {
    Dictionary<string, Detector> detectors = new Dictionary<string, Detector>()
    {
        { "A", ModelA(ip, port) },
        { "B", ModelB(ip, port) },
        { "C", ModelC(ip, port) },
        ...
        { "X", ModelX(ip, port) },
    };
    if (modelName = "B" || modelName = "C")
    {
       //special case for these 2 models
    }
    return new detectors[modelName]
}
```

What I am trying to accomplish is stopping the recurring "if/else" which are all identical, but without the initialization of the constructor until I request its value.

Comment: You can't create an object without calling it's constructor. The rest of your question isn't clear

Comment: I cant even find the ***?*** in your post!!! what is your question??

Comment: *To me, this seems rather inefficient* why? your second block it much less efficient. It creates a Dictionary and every object that could be returned and then just returns an object. The first block is much more efficient and makes better logical sense.

Comment: Yes, the second block is inefficient and incorrect. It is creating a Dictionary that is being forgotten anyways after the function executes. There is nothing wrong with the first approach - if you are looking for something concise consider using a `switch` statement.

Comment: @Liam What I would like to know is if there is a way to use a list or dictionary to return an object, or a way to create it when you use the dictionary. I will edit my question, I know what I want but I'm struggling to formulate it.

Comment: @akadian seriously don't. The first block of code is fine. Adding a Dictionary, etc is needless.

Comment: I believe OP is looking for a object pool-like solution. Firstly, I believe it is not suitable for the constructor to try and connect your device, that should be in its own method, following the singularity principle in OOP.

Comment: Reading between the lines, constructing and object calls an Init function that takes time? you get an object from a class multiple times using a factory pattern? Everytime you get a class it takes time to build? It really isn't clear what your problem is or what your posted code is attempting to solve

Comment: @crazyGamer Yes, it is doing that and it is legacy code that I will not be touching. However, this is more for the sake of my own curiosity and trying to expand my knowledge of C#.

Comment: @Liam Looking at the current answers, it seems I am looking for Reflection. A way to create a an object when you want it but be able to access it dynamically instead of repeating simple code. I've seen something similar for assigning variables on a large scale and using a dictionary to create a mapping between the variable that needs to be assigned and the one that will do the assignment. I understand this is probably not the situation to use such a case, but I am looking to expand my knowledge and this may or may not have a use in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i would have the following static field in your class:

```
static Dictionary<string, Func<string, string, Detector>> _detectors = new Dictionary<string, Func<string, string, Detector>>()
{
    { "A", (ip, port)=> new ModelA(ip, port) },
    { "B", (ip, port)=> new ModelB(ip, port) }
};
```

The value of the dictionary is a object factory method:

```
var factory = _detectors[modelName];  // returned type is Func<string, string, Detector>
var result = factory(ip, port);
```

Comment: Combine this with the other answer and viola!

Comment: I find this solution elegant and close to what I was looking for. Just to make sure I understand clearly. This is the same as my initial idea, but when initializing the dictionary it simply creates an anonymous function that returns the new instance of the object, correct?

Comment: @akadian Yes, it only creates the object when it is called. I've changed the lower code snipped to get a better understanding

Answer (score 3):

It seems that you are looking for *Reflection*, something like this:

```
using System.Reflection;

...

//DONE: do not recreate the dictionary, but create it once as a static field
static Dictionary<string, Detector> detectors = new Dictionary<string, Detector>() {
  { "A", typeof(ModelA) },
  { "B", typeof(ModelB) },
   ...
};

public Detector CreateDetector(string modelName, string ip, string port) {
  //TODO: validate modelName

  return detectors[modelName]
    .GetConstructor(new Type[] {typeof(string), typeof(string)})
    .Invoke(new object[] {ip, port}) as Detector;
}
```

If models' names are *regular* (say, *class name* is `"Model" + modelName`) you can go further: drop the dictionary at all and try searching for the model's type

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;

...

public Detector CreateDetector(string modelName, string ip, string port) {
  //TODO: validate modelName

  Type modelType = Assembly
    .GetExecutingAssembly() //TODO: check the assembly
    .GetTypes()
    .Where(t => t.Name == "Model" + modelName)
    .FirstOrDefault();

  if (null == modelType)
    return null; // Not found; you may want to throw exception here

  return modelType
    .GetConstructor(new Type[] {typeof(string), typeof(string)})
    .Invoke(new object[] {ip, port}) as Detector;
}
```

Comment: There is really no efficiency in creating the dictionary in the first place, only to access one particular value and forget the object again. I think it is indicative to guide the OP in the right direction, and not just solve bugs in the code, with all due respect. At least if the Dictionary is made a global or class level variable, it is more sensible, and perhaps what is actually required.

Comment: @crazyGamer: Thank you! I'm totally agree - `detectors` should be a `private static` *field* and not a *local variable*

Comment: @crazyGamer I used it as a local variable to simplify my example. Having it as a global makes it more useful indeed, but it is not of importance to the question at hand. Sorry if that is improper question etiquette, this is my first time posting a question.